# Fields that are changed by AJAX do not go through the submit

Tags: php, ajax, submit, form-submit

I have a form that stopped sending some field values after I added AJAX to the mix.

```
<select name="showId" id="showId" onChange="getClasses('findclasses.php?showId='+this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a Show</option>
    <?
    $sql = "select * from shows order by ShowName";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$show['Id']?>"><?=$show['ShowName']?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>

<div id="classdiv"> //contents reconstructed with AJAX when the show changes above
     <select id="classId" name="classId">
        <option value="">Select Class</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When the show changes, an AJAX function is called, and the contents of the classdiv are replaced with another select field (also named classId) that has the classes associated with the show.

After I click submit, I checked the $_POST variable, and classId was not in the list but the other form fields were.  Any ideas on why and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the select that is injected via ajax has a name attribute on it ?

Comment: Yes.  This is the first line of what it sends back: <select name="classId" id="classId">

Answer (score 0):

Please check that when the contents of classdiv are replaced by ajax the all the option with select tag having their different values or not?

Comment: Firebug reports that they do.  This is one of them.  <option value="3">S1 - Youth Showmanship</option>